# Все возможные разрезы графа

Tags: matlab, graph

Добрый день. Мне нужно найти все возможные разрезы графа. Есть ли решение этой задачи? Буду благодарна за помощь!

Comment: что такое разрез графа в вашем понимании?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Подмножество ребер, удаление которых сделает граф несвязным. Точнее, мне нужно найти все базисные разрезы. Нашла код, в котором используется остовное дерево. Но в этом решение указываются не все разрезы. К примеру, если дан граф, состоящий из 4 вершин, соединенных в виде квадрата, решение дает всего 3 разреза,вместо нужных 6, т.к используется одно остовное дерево. Возможно ли использовать этот метод для нахождения всех разрезов?